# Does Disjunctive Syllogism eliminate one premise?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Would the following example be an accurate representation of valid argument that is a disjunctive syllogism?

```
S or not T
S
Thus, not T
```

My thought process was that it isn't because the not T could be true as well, so we are uncertain of whether it is or not. But I'm not too certain.

Comment: Maybe if "or" means "and" (or "tonk").  That may sound crazy, but the two-valued truth tables for "or" and "and" are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second assumption to "not S" and it would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a variant of a *fallacy* ($T \rightarrow S, S \vdash T$) known as *[affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent)*.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, "or" is inclusive. If you have $P$ or $Q$, you have one of the three: $P$ and $Q$, $P$ and not $Q$, not $P$ and $Q$. So if then you find that $P$ is true, you still have one of the two: $P$ and $Q$, $P$ and not $Q$. So you still don't know anyhing about $Q$.